# When launching app, why is Xcode opening a fullscreen tab named "console" with nothing in it

Tags: xcode

I've never seen this before, but I was working with a new hire today and his Xcode is behaving very strangely. When he Builds and Runs his HelloWorld app, Xcode opens a new Editor Tab labeled "Console" (in Assistant Editor mode). It's not showing the the actual console, it's just opening an empty Editor/Assistant tab. It's remarkably annoying because it hides the code and I have to keep closing the tab.

Here's a video of it:

http://inadaydevelopment.com/stackoverflow/xcode-weirdness-console.mp4

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open Xcode's preferences settings in the Xcode menu item, you can go to the behaviors tab. In the Running-Starts item, disable the show tab named "Console" in "active window". This should fix your problem! Although I have no idea how your new hire happened to enable that completely on accident.